# Windows 10 >= 1809 issues with jacob and Word ComObject

Tags: windows-10, jacob, comobject

we have an old legacy app which uses Java version 1.6 update 45 (jdk-6u45-windows-i586.exe) and Jacob.dll 1.8 (jacob_18.zip), and which cannot be updated :(

Everything was working fine till the latest Windows 10 1809 Update. Since then the comobject behavior seems to have changed and causes an error as well as that the word document cannot be saved anymore. I also tried 19H1 but got the same error.

I could reproduce the issue in java with following code, of course you have to import the Jacob.dll:

```
    import com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent;
    import com.jacob.com.Variant;
    import com.jacob.com.Dispatch;


    ActiveXComponent oWord = new ActiveXComponent("Word.Application");
    oWord.setProperty("Visible", new Variant(true));

    Dispatch documents = oWord.getProperty("Documents").toDispatch();

    String str_file = "C:/temp/test.rtf";

    Dispatch doc = Dispatch.invoke(documents, "Open", Dispatch.Method, 
                            new Object[]{str_file}, 
                            new int[1]).toDispatch();
```

The error I get is:

```
    Exception in thread "main" com.jacob.com.ComFailException: A COM exception has been encountered:

    At Invoke of: Open
    Description: An unknown COM error has occured.
        at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.invokev(Native Method)
        at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.invokev(Dispatch.java:384)
        at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.invoke(Dispatch.java:267)
        at Main.main(Main.java:21)
```

When I click on the Dispatch errors I only get that it is not a valid line number in com.jacob.com.Dispatch

I know it is not the best day not updating the legacy app itself, but what can I say, it is as it is.

Any ideas what might have changed in Windows >= 1809 or how it can be solved without touching the app?

Thanks

Stephan

Edit:

Dispatch oDocument = Dispatch.call(documents, "Open", str_file).toDispatch(); leads to the same error

I should mention that Word opens, but I am not able to save the file and that the return value is an error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception from Word.ApplicationClass.Activedocument all of a sudden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54073785/exception-from-word-applicationclass-activedocument-all-of-a-sudden)

Answer (score 1):

OK, the error is the same which is covered in this post:

[Exception from Word.ApplicationClass.Activedocument all of a sudden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54073785/exception-from-word-applicationclass-activedocument-all-of-a-sudden)

So it seems to be a bug in >=1809 and for the moment the only fix is to change/play with the regional settings